# Bootstrap 3- How to align images above another image with responsive?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Bootstrap. Can someone help me to align and overlap images over another image with responsiveness in bootstrap. I tried as.

```
HTML:
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<img src="images/book_bg.png" class="img-responsive"/>
<ul class="row">
<li class="col-lg-6"><img src="images/Desert.jpg" class="img-responsive"/></li>
<li class="col-lg-6"><img src="images/Hydrangeas.jpg" class="img-responsive"/> </li>
</ul>
<ul class="row">
<li class="col-lg-6"><img src="images/Jellyfish.jpg" class="img-responsive"/></li>
<li class="col-lg-6"><img src="images/Koala.jpg" class="img-responsive"/> </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:
    ul {
        width: 100%;
    }
    li {
        width: 49%;
        float: left;
    }

PROBLEM: Images not aligning to background as shown in fig.Help?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwyjk1QbhhGGRVZxZkgxMk5RNlk/edit?usp=sharing
download the image here

Comment: U can try offsets to position like `col-lg-offset-*`

Comment: images/book_bg.png should be background(via CSS), or you should use absolute positioning

Comment: Hi,

  Thanks for your reply. I changed css as Position:absolute and its working fine. And also using col-offset i am able to move the inner images left-right and vice versa. But, to align it top/bottom whether any property available or i have to simply use css properties like (margin-top,margin-bottom, padding)?
Can someone tell me about aligning images top and bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Include an id in this part of HTML, for example:

```
<img src="images/book_bg.png" class="img-responsive" id="background_image"/>
```

And then add a CSS for this id with an absolute position:

```
#background_image {position: absolute}
```

**About the vertical align from the comment:**

You can find many questions related to this. Here are a few examples:

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008670/vertical-align-image-in-div)
[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-div)
[Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516317/vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div-with-responsive-height)

Comment: Hi,

  Thanks for your reply. I changed css as Position:absolute and its working fine. And also using col-offset i am able to move the inner images left-right and vice versa. But, to align it top/bottom whether any property available or i have to simply use css properties like (margin-top,margin-bottom, padding)?
Can someone tell me about aligning images top and bottom.

Comment: @GaganNaidu I have updated my answer with several links about vertical alignment.