# Fixing Div and Image Height Issue in Thumbnail Layout

Tags: css, image, html, vertical-alignment

I have thumbnail DIVS that are simply an image with the product name below. Here's the code:

```
<div class="thumbs">
<a href="LINK"><img  src="IMAGE" /></a>
<div>Product Name</div>
</div>
```

The CSS is below:

```
.thumbs {
    float:left; width:210px; height:200px; text-align:center;
}

.thumbs div {
}

.thumbs img
{
    max-height: 115px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Originally I had the images at 115px height so every row had the same height images and the text below was aligned correctly. Some of the images became too wide so I had to make a restriction on the max-width.

Problem: Since the image heights vary ... the text below the thumbnail varies in vertical placement. I want the text to be on the same line across the rows.

Example page:
http://test.pillarsoflifebook.com/banquettes/designer-banquettes/
*Note the first 3 thumbnails are the same height .. thus the names below them are aligned

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you are generating the page from a database of images' (etc.) information, then you could store the dimensions of the images and calculate a CSS `padding` in the code on a per-image basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could solve this by wrapping the images in a `div` (or setting your anchor to `display: block`) and setting a `max-height` or `height` on that wrapper, and setting it to `overflow: hidden`.

[Here's a jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/johntobinme/R5T5P/) that will force the thumbnail blocks to always display the same regardless of the size of the image.

Edit: [Updated example with some of your images](http://jsfiddle.net/johntobinme/R5T5P/1/).

Edit2: To vertically align the image inside the anchor, set the `line-height` of the anchor equal to its height (in this case `line-height: 115px;`), and set `vertical-align: middle;` on the `img` itself. [Updated example including this fix here](http://jsfiddle.net/johntobinme/R5T5P/2/).

Comment: This worked great! Only issue is a few of the images are at the top of the Div now. Any way to have them at the bottom (near the text) but padded a bit besides manually adding it to a few of the images?

Example Calypso and Metro Banquettes - notice how they're at the top of the div and far from the text.

http://test.pillarsoflifebook.com/banquettes/designer-banquettes/

Comment: @user40823 Ah, yeah. Vertical aligning is always a tricky thing to figure out, but you can utilise the [fix outlined here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008670/vertical-align-image-in-div). The two key adjustments you need to make: add a `line-height: 115px;` (i.e. the same as the containing element's height) to the anchor, and `vertical-align: middle;` to the `img` itself. [Updated my example here](http://jsfiddle.net/johntobinme/R5T5P/2/), and I'll edit this into my answer as well!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CSS3, you can use css3 translate property.

This Re-sizes based on whatever is bigger. If your height is bigger and width is smaller than container, width will be stretch to 100% and height will be trimmed from both side. Same goes for larger width as well.

```
.thumbs {
    width:210px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.thumbs > .thumbs img {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    min-height:100%;
    display:block;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    min-width:100%;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/shekhardesigner/aYrhG/

Answer from [CSS: How can I set image size relative to parent height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19192892/css-set-image-size-relative-to-parent-height)