# How do I center an image vertically within a div that is position:fixed?

Tags: html, css, centering

I've looked through a lot of various vertical centering techniques, but none are working for me - mainly because I'm using a fixed positioned div.

```
<div id="lightbox">
<div id="lightboxImgContainer">
<img src="' + image_href + '" />
</div>
</div>

#lightbox {
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:#ffffff;
text-align:center;
z-index:4;
display:none;   
}

#lightboxImgContainer
{
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
max-height:100%;
max-width:100%;
text-align:center;
}  

#lightbox img {
max-height: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

Also, am I the only person that thinks its a joke that vertical alignment isn't as simple as horizontal alignment? I've spent far too much time on this to achieve what should be a simple task.

Comment: @Vickel - the question is about centering in a fixed *positioned* element, not a fixed sized element.

Comment: @ Alhoci: the selected answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005244/vertical-align-center-image-in-fixed-size-div is the same like in this post

Comment: @Vickel - Right. But two different questions can have the same answer.

Comment: [Just change `display:none` to `display:table`](http://jsfiddle.net/Nx5pu/)

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to set it as a background image:

```
#lightbox {
  background:url(myimage.jpg) no-repeat center center
}
```

Alternatively, you could use flexbox if you [don't need to support IE <= 9](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

```
#lightbox {
  display: flex;
}
#lightbox img {
  align-items:  center;
}
```

Comment: [Flexbox has poor support.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Comment: What are you talking poor support, even IE has it !

Comment: @Abhishek Only full, no-vendor-prefix support on IE 11, FF 28, Chrome 29, and Android 4.4 Kitkat. Mobile and desktop safari recently updated to the new version of the spec and haven't dropped vendor prefixes.